# Copy row between Google Sheets using Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need some help because I have zero knowledge of Google App Script programming language
and I'm not able to solve this problem; I searched the solution on different forums and I watched a lot of different videos on YouTube but I was not able to change the code as I need.

I'm combining Google Script with MIT App Inventor (this is the page from which I copied the code: https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/google-sheet-crudq-ii) and I need to change the "DELETE" function (the last one) to copy the row to delete into another sheet (called ORP_completati) in the same Google Sheet

```
function doGet(e) {
      
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.ID);
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH); 
      var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ORP_completati");
      var fn = e.parameter.FN;
      var rg = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
      const now = new Date();
     
      // Create/Add new record, using comma separated values
      if ( fn == 'CREATE' ) {
        var data = e.parameter.DATA.split(',');
        sh.appendRow(data);
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("New record created");
      }
      
      // Reads/Returns all data as a stringified JSON List
      else if ( fn == 'READ' ) {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(rg));     
      }
      
      // Edit/Update existing record, requires index/row and current col1 to match
      else if ( fn == 'UPDATE' ) {
        var index = e.parameter.INDEX;  //index in list
        var col1 = e.parameter.COL1;  // current/existing value of col1 - it could be replaced...
        var data = e.parameter.DATA.split(','); //new data
        var range = sh.getRange((parseInt(index)+1),1,1,data.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < rg.length; i++ ) {
          if ( index != undefined && i == index && col1 == rg[i][0] ) {
            range.setValues([data]);
          } 
        }
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("Record updated");    
        }
      
      // deletes a single record (and its row) from sheet. Requires row index and col1 to match
      else if ( fn == 'DELETE' ) {
        var index = e.parameter.INDEX;  //index in list
        var col1 = e.parameter.COL1;  // current/existing value of col1 - it could be replaced...
        for (var i = 0; i < rg.length; i++ ) {
          if ( index != undefined && i == index && col1 == rg[i][0] ) {
            sh.deleteRow(parseInt(index)+1);
          } 
        }
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("Versione 7 mod 9");    
       }
      
    }
```

I hope everything is clear and I want to thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the last column with content (you will need this in order to copy all the columns in the row)

```
var lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn()
```

Second, get the full row. getSheetValues takes 4 values: startRow, startColumn, number of rows and number of columns.

```
var copyRow = sh.getSheetValues(parseInt(index)+1, 1, 1, lastColumn)
```

Third, append the row to the logSheet sheet - Keep in mind that getSheetValues returns a 2D array and the appendRow function only takes a 1D array so you have to pass the first element.

```
logSheet.appendRow(copyRow[0])
```

Finally, you can delete the row

```
sh.deleteRow(parseInt(index)+1);
```

Resources:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetValues(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents